# The constructor Object(String) is undefined

Tags: super

I get *The constructor Object(String) is undefined* on "super("title")". It's not just this piece of code, every single program I create, containing "super" has the error, which leads me to believe, that the problem is of general nature (eclipse/missing import).
Thanks

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;            
import javax.swing.JFrame;               
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;            
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class MouseEventHandling {
   private JPanel mousepanel;
   private JLabel statusbar;           

    public MouseEventHandling() {
        super("title");

        mousepanel = new JPanel();
        mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extend your class from JFrame